# Search bar behavior similar to native Contacts app, but with a refresh control

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, uirefreshcontrol

I've followed the steps in the accepted answer of this question: [Sticky search bar and section header behavior similar to native Contacts app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759506/sticky-search-bar-and-section-header-behavior-similar-to-native-contacts-app/14798981#14798981)

All works fine, but I want to add a `UIRefreshControl` to the table view. It also works fine, but after refreshing, the table view is not displaying correctly. It seems that the `UIRefreshControl` is not handling the inset for the search bar in the table view.

Here you can see the `UITableView`and the `UISearchBar` before pulling down:
[image]

And here you can see the `UITableView`and the `UISearchBar` after releasing: 
[image]

How can I solve this? Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The problem was that I forgot to call `UIRefreshControl` `endRefreshing` method when the refreshing operation ended.

Comment: Hi, Could you show your code. How did you put the `UIRefreshControl` and the `UISearchBar` like this? I have both but I put the search bar in Interface Builder and the refresh control I added as a subview to the table. But now I can't see the refresh control in the search results. I tried using the search bar as the table view header but it gave me errors.