# Sticky header on elements in VBox

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, user-interface, layout

I have a `VBox` with some container elements in it. The `VBox` has a limited height and enables scrolling if its elements exceed its height.

Each of its child elements have a "header" element. In case of scrolling, I would like the header element to always be visible even if the container is "clipped" by the scrolling,
exactly like the iPhone contacts application (see [this question where the behavior is described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759506/sticky-search-bar-and-section-header-behavior-similar-to-native-contacts-app), my headers correspond to *A*, *B*, etc.).
I also have a bottom element that should behave similarly, sticking to the bottom of the visible area of the canvas.

I have been trying to accomplish this by listening on mouse events to detect scrolling and manually correct the position of the header and bottom elements like this:

```
private function updateTopBottomPosition():void {
    var host:DisplayObjectContainer = owner;

    var global0:Point = host.localToGlobal(new Point(0, 0));
    var global1:Point = host.localToGlobal(new Point(host.width, host.height));

    //transform parent global coordinates to local frame
    var local0:Point = this.globalToLocal(global0);
    var local1:Point = this.globalToLocal(global1);

    var maxTop:Number = this.height;
    var minBottom:Number = this.height; // - topLabel.height

    var top:Number = local0.y;
    top = Math.max(0, top);
    top = Math.min(this.height, top);

    topLocalDistance = top;

    var bottom:Number = this.height - local1.y;
    bottom = Math.max(0, bottom);
    bottom = Math.min(this.height, bottom);

    bottomLocalDistance = bottom;

    if(prevBottomLocalDistance == bottomLocalDistance && topLocalDistance == prevTopLocalDistance)
        return;

    prevBottomLocalDistance = bottomLocalDistance;
    prevTopLocalDistance = topLocalDistance;

    //while there is changes, try again
    setTimeout(updateTopBottomPosition, 1);
}
```

It does work *okay*, and I have uploaded the source code for a complete working prototype **[HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojajolx7zzcqe6f/FloatingHeader.rar)**.

Unfortunately, the user experience with this approach is bad; the components do not move fluently and the positioning does not always update correctly.

I have not been able to find a component or an approach that is able to achieve the effect in question seamlessly. I would be grateful if anyone could point me in direction of something that would be able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I've misuderstood, but any reason you can't just use an additional layout of nesting?

```
container
 - header container
 - vbox with scroller
```

Comment: There are multiple headers inside the `VBox`, all need the 'sticky' feature. Haven't you seen the link I provided with the iPhone contacts as example?

Comment: I'm not clear why they need to be in the vbox.  I was suggesting moving them outside into another container, then wrapping both of them in a container (group?).

Comment: I am not following, can you elaborate in your answer? The elements are in a `VBox` because the need to be stacked on top of each other. Each of the elements has a header that needs to be positioned dynamically according to the scroll position as described in the question.